# Finding the rows of a matrix with specified elements

Tags: matlab

I want to find the rows of a matrix which contain specified element of another matrix.

For example, `a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]` and `b=[1 2 0 4;0 9 10 11;3 1 2 12]`. Now, I want to find the rows of `b` which contain at least three element of `a`. For this purpose, I used `bsxfun` command as following:

```
c=find(sum(any(bsxfun(@eq, b, reshape(a,1,1,[])), 2), 3)>=3);
```

It works good for low dimension matrices but when I want to use this for high dimension matrices, for example, when the number of rows of `b` is `192799`, MATLAB gives following error:

```
Requested 192799x4x48854 (35.1GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. 
Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB 
to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.
```

Is there any other command which does this task without producing the behaviour like above for high dimension matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possible solution:

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7] 
b=[1 2 0 4;0 9 10 11;3 1 2 12]
i=ismember(b,a)
idx = sum(i,2)
idx = find(idx>=3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I think this code is faster than bsxfun too

Comment: I 'm glad if it can help